# SQL Count Percentage from Multiple Tables with Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, count, percentage, multiple-tables

I have three tables:
Table Clothes

| id | clothname | supplier | instock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shirt | Venom | Yes |
| 2 | Tshirt | Traders | No |

Table Toys

| id | toyname | instock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | Yes |
| 2 | Ball | Yes |
| 2 | Yoyo | N/A |

Table Tools

| id | toolname | instock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Drill | Yes |
| 2 | Hammer | No |

I would like single SQL query to count percentage of all products from 3 tables, where Instock = Yes
From table Clothes there are two conditions, instock = Yes and supplier = Venom.

Desired output would be:
Percentage of products in stock: XY% percent

```
| Status   | Percentage from total Products  |
+----------+---------------------------------+
| Instock  |              57.14              |
```

What would be the SQL query for this?

Comment: Percentage from total Products=0.6667 not 57.14. 57.14 is for all supplier.

Answer (score 1):

Your data

```
CREATE TABLE Clothes (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  clothname VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL, 
  supplier VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
  instock VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Clothes(id, clothname, supplier, instock) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Shirt', 'Venom', 'Yes'), 
  (2, 'Tshirt', 'Traders', 'No');
CREATE TABLE Toys (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  toyname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  instock VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Toys(id, toyname, instock) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Car', 'Yes'), 
  (2, 'Ball', 'Yes'), 
  (2, 'Yoyo', 'N/A');
CREATE TABLE Tools (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  toyname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  instock VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Tools(id, toyname, instock) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Drill', 'Yes'), 
  (2, 'Hammer', 'No');
```

Use `union all` and `cte` as follows

```
WITH T AS
(
       SELECT id,
              clothname,
              instock
       FROM   Clothes
       WHERE  supplier='Venom'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM   Toys
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM   Tools)

SELECT Instock                              AS status,
       Cast(Count(*) AS FLOAT) / (SELECT Count(*)
                                  FROM   T) AS 'Percentage from total Products'
FROM   T
WHERE  Instock = 'Yes'
GROUP  BY Instock
```

desired output

| status | Percentage from total Products |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | 0.666666666666667 |

Comment: This is working, but not giving the right percentage (it should be 57.14). 
From first table > FROM   Clothes  WHERE  supplier='Venom' should be also Instock = Yes.

Comment: where condition in Clothes exclude second record of it, hence it increase the percentage(0.667), by removing where condition the  percentage=57.14

Comment: ok, possible to include where condition in Clothes and get the right percentage=57.14? Only Clothes table should have condition Where supplier='Venom' AND Instock='Yes'. Other tables just need condition Instock='Yes'

Comment: In above query(cte), the Instock='Yes' condition  has been considered.

Comment: I get an error with this query: 1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.  And another error (due to MariaDB v10) - Unrecognised statement type (near WITH ). Possible to sort this with subquery?

Comment: It is possible to use subquery [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92a85bd7ec76a5de4e50969a9e1df6a9)